# google closure compiler annotations for passing enums

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I can't seem to find the correct closure-compiler annotations to pass a map of enums around.

E.g: Given EventTargets `A`, `B` with:

```
/** @enum {string} */
MYNS.A.EventType = {EA : 'ea1'};

/** @enum {string} */
MYNS.B.EventType = {EB : 'eb2'};
```

I have a constructor `C` that returns multiple EventTypes:

```
/** @return {WHATSTHIS} */
C.prototype.getEventTypesAB = function() {
  return {
    A: MYNS.A.EventType,
    B: MYNS.B.EventType
  };
};
```

to be used later:

```
goog.events.listen(parent, c.getEventTypesAB().A.EA, ...);
```

I've tried a few things such as below, which I guess doesn't work as `enum` is not a `type`, but am out of ideas of how to annotate this:

```
/** @typedef {{ A: MYNS.A.EventType, B: ... }} */
```

I always end up with the (expected) compiler warning: `WARNING - Property EA never defined on String` at the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MYNS.A.EventType` is an object whose keys are strings and whose values are members of that enum. So you could write

`/** @type {!Object<string, MYNS.A.EventType>} */ var obj = MYNS.A.EventType`

and it would typecheck. Likewise for B. So the type of the object literal that you're returning is a record type, `{A: !Object<string, MYNS.A.EventType>, B: !Object<string, MYNS.B.EventType>}`

Comment: yep, the difference between an instance of a type and the type of the object defining a type is sometimes confusing.

Answer (score -1):

This code compiles with the [online Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Agoog.provide(%2522MYNS.A.EventType%2522)%253B%250Agoog.provide(%2522MYNS.B.EventType%2522)%253B%250Agoog.provide(%2522MYNS.C.ComboType%2522)%253B%250Agoog.provide(%2522MYNS.C%2522)%253B%250A%252F**%2520%2540enum%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520*%252F%250AMYNS.A.EventType%2520%253D%2520%257BEA%2520%253A%2520'ea1'%257D%253B%250A%252F**%2520%2540enum%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520*%252F%250AMYNS.B.EventType%2520%253D%2520%257BEB%2520%253A%2520'eb2'%257D%253B%250A%252F**%2520%2540typedef%2520%257B%257B%2520A%253A%2520MYNS.A.EventType%252C%2520B%253A%2520MYNS.B.EventType%2520%257D%257D%2520*%252F%250AMYNS.C.ComboType%253B%250AMYNS.C%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540return%2520%257B!MYNS.C.ComboType%257D%2520*%252F%250AC.prototype.getEventTypesAB%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520return%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520A%253A%2520MYNS.A.EventType%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520B%253A%2520MYNS.B.EventType%250A%2520%2520%257D%253B%250A%257D%253B%250Avar%2520foo%2520%253D%2520new%2520C()%253B%250Avar%2520r%2520%253D%2520foo.getEventTypesAB()%253B%250Aconsole.log(r.A.EA)%253B%250Aconsole.log(r.B.EB)%253B%250A%250A):

```
goog.provide("MYNS.A.EventType");
goog.provide("MYNS.B.EventType");
goog.provide("MYNS.C.ComboType");
goog.provide("MYNS.C");
/** @enum {string} */
MYNS.A.EventType = {EA : 'ea1'};
/** @enum {string} */
MYNS.B.EventType = {EB : 'eb2'};
/** @typedef {{ A: MYNS.A.EventType, B: MYNS.B.EventType }} */
MYNS.C.ComboType;
MYNS.C = function() {};
/** @return {!MYNS.C.ComboType} */
C.prototype.getEventTypesAB = function() {
  return {
    A: MYNS.A.EventType,
    B: MYNS.B.EventType
  };
};
var foo = new C();
var r = foo.getEventTypesAB();
console.log(r.A.EA);
console.log(r.B.EB);
```

I haven't tried to run the resulting simple-compiled code, but it seems like it should work.  Here is what the compiler gives with simple-compile and pretty print:

```
var MYNS = {A:{}, B:{}};
MYNS.A.EventType = {EA:"ea1"};
MYNS.B.EventType = {EB:"eb2"};
MYNS.C = function() {
};
C.prototype.getEventTypesAB = function() {
  return {A:MYNS.A.EventType, B:MYNS.B.EventType};
};
var foo = new C, r = foo.getEventTypesAB();
console.log(r.A.EA);
console.log(r.B.EB);
```

I think the step you are missing is to define the type with a namespace name as in these lines:

```
/** @typedef {{ A: MYNS.A.EventType, B: MYNS.B.EventType }} */
MYNS.C.ComboType;
```

That is what is shown on this page, which I consider the most helpful page about Google Closure syntax:

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags